# href link is not working in subdomain folder

Tags: php, html, mysql

My subdomain is sample and consider my domain name is demodomain.I want to link 'www.google.com'.
My href will link to 'http://www.sample.demodomain.com/www.google.com'.

```
html code:
   <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">click me</a>
```

I want to be  redirected  to www.google.com.but now I get redirected to http://www.sample.demodomain.com/www.google.com.

Comment: So you just want to redirect to google?

Comment: `href="http://google.com"` ??

Comment: its actually `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put http:// in href before the url

Answer (score 2):

You need to have http:// in the URL you would like to be redirected to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add http://.
If you don't the browser thinks that you want to link to an htmlpage or a file called "www.google.com" not the original website
so here you are:

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">click me</a>
```

Comment: This also get redirect to  'http://www.sample.demodomain.com/www.google.com' in new tab